# Game Incorporate Computer Choice Math Random Class

Tags: java, user-interface, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to design a Rock Paper Scissors game with a gui in Java.  I've read the many different tutorials online and the ones asked here but none really had the problem I am having so I am hoping someone can help me.  I have everything working (just ugly right now; I will make it look better once the game actually functions). I have three issues and all but one is small.  First, I cannot get the user and computer label to show up.  Second issue is how would I go about actually having the game say "you picked" and "the computer picked"? Lastly, how do I incorperate the computer to choose a choice?  I realize I will have to use the math class and a random but how would I make the computer actually choose its' choice?

here is my driver class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class GameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rock Paper Scissors");
        GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here is my other class which includes the actual idea I have for the choosing without the computer making a choice.  Any tips and help I will greatly appreciate.  I thank you to everything.Again, thank you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


 public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
     private JLabel userLabel, computerLabel, resultLabel, winLabel, tieLabel, loseLabel;
     private JButton rockButton, paperButton, scissorsButton;
     private int winInt, tieInt, loseInt;
  public GamePanel(){
      winInt = 0;
      tieInt= 0;
      loseInt = 0;
      rockButton = new JButton("Rock");
      paperButton = new JButton("Paper");
      scissorsButton = new JButton("Scissors");

      //action listeners
      rockButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      paperButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      scissorsButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

      add(rockButton);
      add(paperButton);
      add(scissorsButton);

      setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker());
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
  }

  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

          Object userSource = ae.getSource();
          Object computerSource = ae.getSource();
          if (userSource == rockButton && computerSource == scissorsButton){
              winInt++;
          }else if (userSource == paperButton && computerSource == rockButton){
              winInt++;
          }else if (userSource == scissorsButton && computerSource == paperButton){
              winInt++;
          }else  if (computerSource == rockButton && userSource == scissorsButton){
              loseInt++;
          }else if (computerSource == paperButton && userSource == rockButton){
              loseInt++;
          }else if (computerSource == scissorsButton && userSource == paperButton){
              loseInt++;
          }else{
              tieInt++;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to start learning programming with console programs. Get an intro book, work through the chapters.

Comment: This was the project from the book already lol.  >_<.  I mean I did fine till this last three things. Now I am stuck and researching has not helped at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might go about getting a random choice for a computer player.

```
public String getRandomChoice(){
        double d = Math.random();

        if(d < .33){
            return "ROCK";
        }
        else if(d < .66){
            return "PAPER";
        }
        else{
            return "SCISSORS";
        }
    }
```

Try this link to get some info on how to code a GUI in Java for a RPS game.  http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/swing/rockPaperScissors